# Como inserir uma constantes numa linha de PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Olá, estou com umas dificuldades na apresentação de dados.

```
with atores(nome, data_nasc) as (select nome, data_nasc from representa inner join artistas using(n_artista))
    ,realizadores(nome, data_nasc) as (select nome, data_nasc from realiza inner join artistas using(n_artista))
    ,autores(nome, data_nasc) as (select nome, data_nasc from escreve inner join artistas using(n_artista))

select nome,
case 
     when exists(select * from realizadores where realizadores.nome = artistas.nome and realizadores.data_nasc = artistas.data_nasc) then 'Realizador'
     when exists(select * from autores where autores.nome = artistas.nome and autores.data_nasc = artistas.data_nasc) then 'Autor'
     when exists(select * from atores where atores.nome = artistas.nome and atores.data_nasc = artistas.data_nasc) then 'Ator'
end as tipo_artista
from artistas;
```

Este é o código que tenho de momento e funciona parcialmente, eu quero que apareça o nome de cada artista e depois também o tipo de artista que ele é, só que o código falha quando tenho um artista que é mais do que um tipo de artista, por exemplo se for autor e ator ao mesmo tempo, só aparece a linha que diz que ele é Autor suponho que ser por ser o primeiro que aparece na cláusula CASE.

Existe forma de eu inserir o tipo_artista de artista de outro modo?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: e quando ele é mais de tipo o que pretende fazer? tem algum critério para escolher algum, que tenha mais prioridade?

Comment: No lugar de um case "tipo_artista" três cases um para realizador , autor e ator, sem entrar no mérito da query em si que talvez ficasse melhor com três joins a mais.

Comment: não, eu queria que aparece-se os dois tipos, em duas linhas diferentes aparecia o nome repetido mas o tipo diferente

Comment: Talvez possa fazer de forma mais simples com o uso de UNION e ORDER BY nome.

Comment: eu até tenho estado a meter order by nome mas diz identificador invalido

Answer (score 0):

```
with atores(nome, tipo) as (select nome, case when 1=1 then 'Ator' end as tipo from representa inner join artistas using(n_artista))
    ,realizadores(nome, tipo) as (select nome, case when 1=1 then 'Realizador' end as tipo from realiza inner join artistas using(n_artista))
    ,autores(nome, tipo) as (select nome,case when 1=1 then 'Autor' end as tipo from escreve inner join artistas using(n_artista))
select nome nome_artista, tipo tipo_artista
from (select * from autores) union all (select * from realizadores) union all (select * from atores);
```

Fiz assim e deu mas não sei se vai ser aceite lol

Entretanto como já disse num comentário, não consigo meter "order by nome" no final, dá identificador inválido